# btrfs check /dev/loop0 -> ERROR: cannot open file system

Tags: filesystems, btrfs, fsck, loop-device

I have a file formatted as a btrfs filesystem.  I can loop mount it and use it normally.  I'd like to run `btrfs check` on this file, but an error is generated.

First I tried with just the file:

```
$ sudo btrfs check ./sage-M.btrfs 
couldn't open because of unsupported option features (10).
ERROR: cannot open file system
```

That didn't work so I thought maybe it needed to be a device, but that doesn't seem to help:

```
$ sudo losetup --show -v -P -f ./sage-M.btrfs 
/dev/loop0
$ sudo btrfs check /dev/loop0
couldn't open because of unsupported option features (10).
ERROR: cannot open file system
```

What is/are "option features (10)"?  How can I run `btrfs check` on this file?

BTW:

```
$ sudo btrfs --version
btrfs-progs v4.9.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "unsupported option features" means that the BTRFS filesystem in the file has features enabled which are not supported by either your BTRFS tools or Linux kernel. This can happen when:

- The filesystem was created with a version of `btrfs-progs` which is newer than the version currently in use.
- The Linux kernel has been downgraded, causing the BTRFS kernel-space code to lose functionality required by the filesystem in question. You can see a kernel version to BTRFS features mapping [here](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Changelog#By_feature).

An example would be if the filesystem uses ZSTD compression yet `btrfs-progs` is an older version which does not support ZSTD.

Comment: Could using `mount` option `compress=zstd` with my version of `btrfs-progs` be the issue?

Comment: ... for example, maybe here my kernel is _ahead_ of my `btrfs-progs`.  And is there a mapping from "option features (XX)" to something concrete?  What is "10" here?

Comment: I don't thing so, but you can test the theory by not using ZSTD compression; It won't hurt anything to try. I once found a mapping for the confusing "10", but I don't remember where. If you run `mkfs.btrfs -O list-all` you'll get a list of the features supported by `btrfs-progs`, but I don't know how to list the features of a specific BTRFS filesystem. Try asking in the BTRFS IRC chat on freenode or on their mailing list.

Comment: `btrfs inspect-internal dump-super ./sage-M.btrfs` shows, in addition to many other things, `incompat_flags 0x155 ( ... unknown flag: 0x10 )`.  Looking at my tagged version of `btrfs-progs` for file `ctree.h`, `BTRFS_FEATURE_INCOMPAT_SUPP` does not include the `ZSTD` flag.  So, your initial statement is correct, "... the BTRFS filesystem in the file has features enabled which are not supported by either your BTRFS tools ...". In my case, the kernel is using features that are not present in my `btrfs-progs`. Fedora `btrfs-progs` lag features present in the kernel. An issue has been submitted.

Comment: If you update your answer, I'll upvote and accept.

Comment: I cloned GitHub's `btrfs-progs` repo and built the `master` branch on my computer.  `btrfs check ./sage-M.btrfs` worked fine.

Comment: And now Fedora has updated `btrfs-progs` so everything is working OK.